# How to Change Magento2 SOAP API response from Object to XML

Tags: php, api, soap, magento2

I have created a custom Magento2 Soap API to get data from a third party server and save it into Magento DB.
Everything is working fine with data processing. Now When I print the result it is in an Object form but I need it in XML format only.
Here is the code I am using to make the request:

```
 $wsdlurl = 'MagentoStore/soap?wsdl&services=CustomDataApiManagementV1';
 $token = 'XXXXXXXXXXXX';
    $opts = ['http' => ['header' => "Authorization: Bearer " . $token]];
    $context = stream_context_create($opts);
    $addArgs = array('xmldata'=> 'testData');

    try{
        $soapClient = new SoapClient($wsdlUrl);
        $soapClient->setSoapVersion(SOAP_1_2);
        $soapClient->setStreamContext($context);
        $soapResponse = $soapClient
                     ->CustomDataApiManagementV1ProcessData($addArgs);
        print_r($soapResponse);
    }catch(Exception $e){
        echo 'error';
    }
```

> > This print_r($soapResponse) is showing result as below:

**stdClass Object ( [result] => success )**

I need result in XML format only.

Please do let me know if anyone has already worked on it.

Comment: Have you tried `wddx_serialize_value` function to convert your object in to xml? like this `echo wddx_serialize_value($soapResponse);`

Comment: Thanks for your response, Shahroze! In this way, we can only change the data at the client site i.e. from where we are making a request to Magento SOAP API. BUt I to change this response at Magento API end, so the API requesting users won't need to do it at their end.

Comment: @ManjuCh May i know how you solved this issue?

Comment: @Gem: It wasn't solved actually, We just modified the code at third party end to use it in Object form instead of XML.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code

```
$soapResponse = array_flip((array) $soapResponse);
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<root/>');
array_walk_recursive($soapResponse, array ($xml, 'addChild'));
print $xml->asXML();
```

Your will get result like below

```
<root><result>Success</result></root>
```

Source from [How to convert array to SimpleXML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1397036/how-to-convert-array-to-simplexml)

Comment: Hi,

Thank you for your response.
Actually, I want to change it at the server end, not at the client end.
i.e.
  $soapResponse = $soapClient
                     ->CustomDataApiManagementV1ProcessData($addArgs); 
 $soapResponse should be in XML format.

Comment: Is there any specific reason for your $soapResponse  in xml format?. I am not sure Response will get xml format.